# Wix CustomAction to run only in basic mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My wix 3.5 setup can be downloaded and run in normal installation situation. I also use the same msi for updates and call `msiexec` with `/qb` (basic quiet interface) from within the app itself.

All is ok up to here. In normal setups, I have an option to start app upon install (taken from tutorial) and works fine.

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Start $(var.AppName) $(var.ExeVersion) now..." />
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#$(var.AppName).exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

I want my update to be quiet and start the updated app after successfull install. In order to do this I have a custom action like this in my `InstallExecuteSequence`:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize"/>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplication"
          After="RemoveExistingProducts"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This is also ok too, however obviously, now my app is automatically started with normal (not /qb) setups. In order to overcome this, I suppose I need to detect in which `UILevel` I am and run the custom action only in `INSTALLUILEVEL_BASIC`.

So here is my question: How can I detect the `UILevel` in `InstallExecuteSequence` or `CustomAction`? Or is there a way to run CustomAction only in quiet basic mode in Wix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should condition condition the custom action by UILevel = 3

Comment: I know but how do I condition it to uilevel 3 exactly?

Comment: You can specify the condition in the text of the "Custom" element.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Here is the working example for reference: <Custom Action="LaunchApplication"
              After="RemoveExistingProducts">UILevel = 3</Custom>